# How to prevent bundled libraries from AMD behavior when RequireJS is present

Tags: webpack, requirejs, browserify

I have a JavaScript bundle that is loaded over HTTP into a client's page, which uses RequireJS to load its dependencies. I use WebPack to compile my JavaScript bundle, which includes a number of npm JS packages such as lodash. These are **bundled into** my package (using npm). My bundle **also** needs to dynamically load a 3rd party JS library over HTTP, which it does by injecting a  block into the client's page. This diagram shows the moving parts:

[image: architecture]

The 3rd party library also bundles its own modules. I happen to know it uses Browserify to do that.

The problem I have is that various npm packages (like lodash) have AMD code like this in their published:

```
  // Some AMD build optimizers like r.js check for condition patterns like the following:
  if (typeof define == 'function' && typeof define.amd == 'object' && define.amd) {
    // Expose lodash to the global object when an AMD loader is present to avoid
    // errors in cases where lodash is loaded by a script tag and not intended
    // as an AMD module. See http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch for
    // more details.
    root._ = _;

    // Define as an anonymous module so, through path mapping, it can be
    // referenced as the "underscore" module.
    define(function() {
      return _;
    });
  }
```

As a result, when my JS bundle runs, lodash tries to become global, interfering with the global _ variable in the client's HTML page, which is underscore. I completely lose the benefit of bundling lodash using WebPack. I have already worked-around this by creating a custom non-AMD build of lodash, and checking its source into my bundle as a module, instead of using npm.

However, this approach won't work for the third-party JS library, which I need to dynamically load directly into the page. That library's npm modules that are AMD-compliant *also* behave differently because RequireJS is on the page.

I assume there must be some way to work-around this, presumably at the RequireJS level.

So far, I have tried:

A) Using a shim in the RequireJS config for both the bundle and the 3rd party library:

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'myBundle': {  exports: 'myBundle' },
    'my3rdPartyLibrary': {exports: 'my3rdPartyLibrary'}
  },

  paths: {
    'myBundle': 'http://example.org/myBundle.js',
    'my3rdPartyLibrary': 'http://example.net/library.js'
  }
});
```

B) Passing lodash in via RequireJS:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'lodash': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js'
  },
  map: {
    'http://example.org/myBundle.js': {
      'underscore': 'lodash'
    },
    'http://example.net/library.js': {
      'underscore': 'lodash'
    }
  }
});
```

(This doesn't solve the issue for other modules, that also contain AMD code.)

C) As mentioned above, a custom lodash build. This works in my bundle, but it doesn't work for the 3rd-party library.

If there is some solution at build time to tell WebPack (and Browserify) to strip any AMD-specific behaviors in bundled modules, that could work. Although the 3rd-party library isn't mine, I could work with the vendor to update their build.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I did a little hack:

```javascript
define.amd = false;
```

Why this way? Because most of the factory functions which are looking for RequireJS are doing:

```javascript
if (define && define.amd) {
    // define as AMD module
}
```

So this does the trick and cheat the 3rd parties

Comment: I came across a similar recommendation somewhere else. The problem is it only works in the code I control (myBundle.js), and not in anything that a 3rd party library might load asynchronously. I can't permanently mess with define() because other libraries (loaded by RequireJS) might need it.

Comment: You are correct. Sadly I do not have solution for that, sorry :(